# Solution of nonlinear differential equation $g = c_1 f^2 + c_2 (f')^2$ for function $f$

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, differential-operators

I would like to find an analytic solution (if possible) of the differential equation:

$g = c_1 f^2 + c_2 (f')^2$

Where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants, $g$ is a known function of $x$, $f$ is another function of $x$ which I'm trying to find, and $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. This equation came up when trying to find a sound pressure field related to $f$ such that one gets a required sound radiation force which is related to $g$.

If a general solution is not possible, what about the case of $g = c_3 x^2$?

EDIT:

As suggested by @MichaelEngelhardt, for $g = c_3 x^2$ being a potential function, one can add a constant to it and change the function to: $g = c_3 x^2 + c_3 c_2 / c_1$. In that case one solution to the ODE is $f = \sqrt{c_3/c_1} x$

Comment: note that you can change $c_2$ using $f(\lambda x)$ and make it equal to $c_1$; so you can absorb both into $g$ and assume w.l.o.g. $c_1=c_2=1$

Comment: Look for weak solutions with convex integration.

Comment: For $g=\lambda x^n$ this can be transformed to an Abel equation. Taking $f'=\lambda^{1/2}x^{n/2}\cos(\xi)$, $f=\lambda^{1/2}x^{n/2}\sin(\xi)$, and $x-n\tan(\xi)/2=u$ we have the equation 
\begin{align}
uu'_\xi+\left(\frac n2\sec(\xi)^2-1\right)u=\frac{n}{2}\tan(\xi).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This ODE is extremely unlikely to have an explicit solution. Mathematica cannot do anything with this ODE even when $g(x)\equiv x$.

Here is an image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]

And here is [a link](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZA40TVZCAyy3X73DjYvXzl1ySX8IybILJ07) to the Mathematica notebook itself.

Comment: Thank you losif. Yes it does not look like it can be solved, except maybe changing it to a Riccati equation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: @Alex : Riccati is a very different kind of ODE.

Comment: Another thing to try is taking a derivative to get something like: $c_3 f f' + c_4 f' f'' - g' = 0$ but I'm not sure how to solve this either

Comment: @Alex : I am sure that Mathematica tries all such simple transformations. That it cannot do anything even for $g(x)\equiv x$ suggests very strongly that the problem is hopeless.

Comment: What if $g$ is $c_3 x^2$?

Comment: @Alex : I have updated the Mathematica notebook. Mathematica cannot do anything with $g(x)=x^2$ either.

Comment: If you allow for a certain constant, $g=c_3 x^2 + c_3 c_2 /c_1 $, there's a simple solution. Maybe one can arrange the physics application to allow for this constant?

Comment: Hi @MichaelEngelhardt, as a matter of fact there is; the function $c_3 x^2$ is a needed Gor'kov potential that from what I understand can have any constant in front of it. In that case, what would the solution be?

Comment: Well, then $f=\sqrt{c_3 / c_1} x$ is a solution.

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt, what about a solution with an offset? Like $g = k_1$ if $x < x_i$ and $g = c_3 (x-x_i)^2 + k_2$ if $x > x_i$ (with solution $f = \sqrt{c_3/c_1} (x-x_i)$). This could be for a ring of high pressure that produces a sound radiation force field. The solution you propose seems to work with $k_2 = c_3 c_2/c_1$ but $k_1$ has to be 0 and can't be equal to $k_2$. Are there any conditions for a potential where these constants have to be same at any point in space?

Comment: @Alex - the shift per se is a red herring; you can always shift the definition of the $x$ coordinate without changing the character of the problem. So we can leave $x_i =0$ wlog. However, concerning piecing together the previous solution with a constant solution, $g=k_1 $ and $f=\sqrt{k_1 /c_1 } $, the requirement is that $f$ be continuous, otherwise you'll get in trouble with the $f' $ term. That means you have to piece together at $x=\sqrt{k_1 /c_3 } $, and then $g$ has a discontinuity of $c_3 c_2 /c_1 $ at that $x$. If that is ok from the application point of view, you have a solution.

Comment: Hi @MichaelEngelhardt, yes I want $f$ to be continuous; it corresponds to an averaged sound pressure, I would like it to be zero from $x=0$ to $x=x_i$ and then ramp up, i.e. $f=\sqrt{c_3/c_1} (x-x_i)$. This works if I allow the potential $g$ to be discontinuous: equal to 0 from $x=0$ to $x=x_i$ and then $g = c_3 (x-x_i)^2 + c_3 c_2/c_1$ for $x > x_i$. This seems to work out numerically, but physically can a potential have a discontinuity? This particular potential is the Gor'kov potential

Comment: @Alex - In general, a potential can be discontinuous (say, to describe an interface), but whether that's the case for your particular potential, I can't judge.